# Can't access secrets of azure bot I created

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service

I am trying to access the secrets and certificates section of my azure web app bot (configuration > app ID > manage), however, I am repeatedly being blocked from doing so and receiving the message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". This is the only resource I have created on my account, and its a brand new account- how do I not have permission to access the thing I created?

Additionally, trying to access other sections of the configuration such as API permissions or manifest gives the same error.

I have tried creating the bot as a web app bot and as the newer azure bot, but both have the same result. I even tried making a new azure account and starting from scratch and that didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: You need to open a ticket in Azure with Azure Support as the issue you are running into is not specific to the bot service.

Comment: The issue is related to AAD permissions, we asked for Azure Support and they forwarded it to the azure active directory team. Looking forward them to resolve this issue for more than a week so far. Hopefully, they can fix this soon, as it seems to be a global issue.

Comment: I am running into this exact issue. Any resolution?

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was caused by invalid page url: azure was insiting on adding unnecessary `true` at end of it. Took me about hour to figure it out.

Just keep in mind to only remove `true` and keep the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are two backslashes in url..
[url pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKiIO.png)
I deleted one of the slashes after objectid and then it works.